# How to manage click event in recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I am creating a contact application where am using the Recycler View to list the items . The recycler view is working fine and list the items well as seen in the picture below

[image: The contactlist page]

Now I want the each contact click to transfer its details to another layout(profile layout) that will look like below

[image]

The recycler adapter works onclick even to just make a Toast but doesnt work for Dialog to transfer data to another layout. I have tried several attempt but proved futile.

### Here is my Adapter

```
package com.example.newcontactapp

import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ContactAdapter (data:ArrayList<ContactClass>, internal var context: Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder>(){

    internal var data : ArrayList<ContactClass>

    init{
        this.data = data
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ContactViewHolder{
        val layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false)
        return ContactViewHolder(layout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:ContactViewHolder, position:Int){

        holder.name.text = data[position].name
        holder.phoneNumber.text = data[position].phone
        holder.image.setImageResource(data[position].image)

        holder.card.setOnClickListener {

            Toast.makeText(context, data[position].name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

//            val profilePage = Dialog(this.context)
//            profilePage.setContentView(R.layout.profile)
////            profilePage.window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL)
//            profilePage.setTitle("Profile page")
//
//            val profileName = profilePage.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.profileName)
//            val profileEmail = profilePage.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.profileEmail)
//            val profileImage = profilePage.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.profileImage)
//
//            profileName.text = data[position].name
//            profileEmail.text = data[position].phone
//            profileImage.setImageResource(data[position].image)
//
//            profilePage.show()

        }


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

    class ContactViewHolder(contactView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(contactView){
        internal var name: TextView
        internal var image: ImageView
        internal var phoneNumber: TextView
        internal var card: ViewGroup;

        init{
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemText)
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage)
            phoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemPhone)
            card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactCard)

        }
    }
}
```

### MainActivity

```
package com.example.newcontactapp

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val contacts = ArrayList<ContactClass>()

        contacts.add(ContactClass("Darot", R.drawable.maleavatar, "080000000000"))
        contacts.add(ContactClass("Lewis", R.drawable.maleavatar, "080000000000"))
        contacts.add(ContactClass("Chigozie", R.drawable.femaleavatar, "080000000000"))
        contacts.add(ContactClass("Chigozie", R.drawable.femaleavatar, "080000000000"))
        contacts.add(ContactClass("Chigozie", R.drawable.femaleavatar, "080000000000"))
        contacts.add(ContactClass("Chigozie", R.drawable.femaleavatar, "080000000000"))
        contacts.add(ContactClass("Chigozie", R.drawable.femaleavatar, "080000000000"))
        contacts.add(ContactClass("Chigozie", R.drawable.femaleavatar, "080000000000"))

        val adapter = ContactAdapter(contacts, applicationContext)
        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        recycler.adapter = adapter

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the Dialog method because I feel it is easier but I got unable to add window error, I tried to bring in an Activity but proved difficult. Kindly help. I am using this as a project for my learning.

Comment: Do not use `applicationContext` for anything UI-related; e.g., your `ContactAdapter`. Use the `Activity` instead; i.e., `this`.

Comment: Thanks Mike the Dialog works now but the WindowsManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL crashes the application. How can I make the Dialog a fullscreen without that

Answer (score 0):

Best Way use Interface for communication between Adapter and Activity.

In activity interface callback show the Dialog using Activity Context as method is implemented in activity so context is available in Activity class.